# Type 1 Error Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, factorial, poisson-distribution

How would one find the probability of a type one error in a poisson distribution?

I know the PDF is f(x/lambda) = ((lambda^x)/(x!))*(e^negativelambda)

Sample Size = 1

My test hypotheses are H0: lambda = 4    and    H1: lambda < 4, Rejecting H0 if X <= 1

I'm particular struggling with the integral that I have set up, which is

integral(-infinity, 1) ((4^x)/(x!))*(e^-4) dx

Answer (score 1):

The Type I error is the probability that, given the null hypothesis is true, the rejection criterion is met.  In your case, this means that $X$ is Poisson distributed with $\lambda = 4$, and you find that $X \le 1$; i.e. $$\Pr[X \le 1 \mid \lambda = 4] = \Pr[X = 0 \mid \lambda = 4] + \Pr[X = 1 \mid \lambda = 4] = e^{-4} \frac{4^0}{0!} + e^{-4} \frac{4^1}{1!}.$$
That's it.  There is no integration involved because $X$ is a discrete-valued random variable, being Poisson distributed.  It is not possible for $X$ to be anything other than a nonnegative integer.